# Make label/button/picturebox image independent of his path

Tags: c#, winforms, assets

I want that all my images for different buttons, label, picture boxes became independent of their path. Here is the code I used for an event that changes my label image only if it's found on the respective location.
How do I make the images independent  of their path, so that I can use them on any PC?

```
private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image i =Image.FromFile(@"d:\utilizator windows10\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ProjectX\ProjectX\w.resurse\close_background.png");
    label1.Image = i;
}
```

Comment: Do you want these assets to be embedded into the application or keep them as separate files?

Comment: I want to embed them into the application

Comment: There are multiple ways then. You can mark the files' Properties as *Embedded Resource* and use relative paths or you could use a *Resource file* and have a strongly-typed `Resources` class.

Comment: ok, I embedded the images, but how do i use them then ?

Answer (score 0):

> ok, I embedded the images, but how do i use them then ?

Then use code like below, replacing "SomeImageName.jpg" with the name of your embedded image:

```
private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Image = new Bitmap(this.GetType(), "SomeImageName.jpg");
}
```